# Using dash line trace out `se` shadow in `stat_smooth`

Tags: r, ggplot2

plot linear regression by using `stat_smooth`:

```
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=runif(10))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
geom_point()+
  stat_smooth(method='lm',se=TRUE)
ggsave('/test.eps')
```

If I set `se=TRUE`, those of shadow area could not save as `eps` file. 
Are there any other `aes` to depict the area of `se`? Such as:
 using two dash curves to trace out the shadow (upper and lower bound of regression prediction). I do not expect to using shadow.

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, the eps format does not support transparency. However you can provide parameters to `stat_smooth` to get rid of transparency (e.g. `alpha=1`) and change the filling color of the SE (`fill="lightgrey"`).

Alternatively, you can provide other geoms than `geom_smooth` to the `stat_smooth` function. E.g. you could try `geom="crossbar"` (or "errobar","linerange","pointrange","ribbon"). However to achieve the desired result you might need to combine difference calls to `stat_smooth` with different geoms.

Lastly, you could compute the CI manually and use `geom_lines`.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = runif(10))

lmdf <- predict(lm(y ~ x, df), interval = "conf") %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  mutate(x = df$x) %>%
  pivot_longer(1:3, names_to = "line", values_to = "y")

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = lmdf, aes(group = line, linetype = line), lwd = 1.2) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dashed", "dashed"))
```

[image]